# Flutter compress an image to a certain size

Tags: flutter, image, compression

I have a class that takes in an image, and returns an image compressed to 50kb. However, an error is occurring in the while loop. It seems to not be reducing image quality past the the first iteration.

```
class CompressToMin {
  static Future<File> compressToMin(File image) async {
    int count = 0;
    print('Size before compression: ${image.lengthSync()}');
    int len = image.lengthSync();
    File? temp = image;
    while (len > 50000) {
      final String fileType = image.path.substring(image.path.lastIndexOf('.'));
      Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      String tempPath = tempDir.path + count.toString() + '.' + fileType;

      temp = await compress(temp!, tempPath);
      count++;
      len = temp!.lengthSync();
      ('length after compression: ${temp.lengthSync()}');
    }

    return temp!;
  }
}

Future<File?> compress(File file, String targetPath) async {
  final result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
    file.absolute.path,
    targetPath,
    quality: 5,
  );

  return result;
}
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're repeatedly trying to compress an image.  I don't think this will work.  Instead, you'll need to retry from the *original* image with *different* quality parameters.

Comment: I see, so i cant recursively lower the quality of an image?

Comment: Only in a very bad way.  You need to make the compress in one step.